# Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'str_to_date'

Tags: mysql, sql, str-to-date

There is a table tab1:

```
|creation_date      | acc_num             | status|
|-------------------|---------------------|-------|
|31.03.2021 07:43:43| 11111111111111111111| deny  |
|31.03.2021 07:43:43| 11111111111111111111| deny  |
|31.03.2021 01:43:20| 22222222222222222222| admit |
|30.03.2020 21:13:21| 33333333333333333333| deny  |
|30.03.2021 20:28:19| 22222222222222222222| deny  |
|30.03.2021 20:28:19| 44444444444444444444| deny  |
```

when I used str_to_date(), I had this uncorrect result and errors.

Query:

```
    select year(str_to_date(creation_date, "%d.%m.%Y %h:%i:%s")) as year
    from tab1;
```

logs:

```
    Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'str_to_date'
    Unknown column 'creation_date' in 'field list'
    Incorrect datetime value: '30.03.2020 21:13:21' for function str_to_date
    ...
    You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')
    from tab1' at line 1
    Incorrect datetime value: '30.03.2020 21:13:21' for function str_to_date
    ...
    Incorrect datetime value: '30.03.2021 20:28:19' for function str_to_date
```

```
result:
|year|
|----|
|2021|
|2021|
|2021|
|[NULL]|
|[NULL]|
|[NULL]|
```

The question is How can I get this result:

```
|year|
|----|
|2021|
|2021|
|2021|
|2020|
|2021|
|2021|
```

MySQL version is 8.0.23

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want the year, why not use a substring operation?  After all, you're storing the value as a string:

```
select substr(creation_date, 7, 4) as year
```

In the meantime, you should fix your table so it stores date/time values using the correct data type.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like  this should work -- check out the fiddle.

```
select year(STR_TO_DATE(c,'%d.%m.%Y'))
from tab;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8cfa2a5/3

Comment: Thanks, it works, but returns errors in logs

Answer (score 1):

You have wrong hour specifier, should be `%H` in order to parse 24-hour format time.

Comment: Caught it!  That was the problem. Thanks!

Comment: @Vadim.M., did you change the accepted answer for a particular reason? Remember, you can mark only a one answer as accepted.

Comment: Yes, sorry. I forgot about it.

Comment: @Vadim.M., no problem, do you mind accepting it back?